# How to upload the image to AWS S3 through postman

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, postman

```js
function uploadPinMedia(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);
    
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: 'mapery-v2'
        }
    })
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx',
        
    });
    var file = req.file;
    
    s3.upload({
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Body: fs.createReadStream(req.file),
        Key: 'upload-v2',

    }, (err, media_res) => {
        console.log(err, media_res)

    });
}
```

I am trying to upload the image to s3 bucket through postman but it is giving me an error like `TypeError: path must be string or buffer`. How to solve this ??

Comment: What is the output of your `console.log(req.file)`?  Are you properly uploading the file in Postman?

Comment: req.file is giving path, original name,fieldname,encoding etc

Comment: @M gowda - so, if `req.file` is an object describing the uploaded file, you'll need to extract the pathname from this and use that value in `s3.upload()`

Comment: Then I need to upload only the path to the s3 bucket ??

Comment: `var file = req.file.path;
    
    s3.upload({
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Body: fs.createReadStream(file),
        Key: 'upload-v2',
    });`
It is not taking the path also